# lighttpd compressing CGI output

Tags: compression, cgi, lighttpd

Is it possible to configure a lighttpd server to compress (gzip encoding) a CGI program output? As opposed to the CGI program compressing its own output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so... at least by now.

Lighttpd documentation about [compressing dynamic content](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modcompress#Compressing-Dynamic-Content) explains how to enable compression in popular frameworks. (PHP, Django, etc.)

Maybe with [mod_deflate](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModDeflate) but only available in the v1.5 release, or with custom patches.